# Segfault when trying to read string from pointer in an injected .dll

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I have a .dll file that's being injected into a game's process. It tries to read a small string from a specific area of memory, but whenever that string is accessed as an std::string, the game crashes. I've only just begun scratching the surface of how program memory works, so I'm lost.

In this game, there are instances of objects that have specific properties. Those properties always have the same offset. The property I am trying to read is the Name property, which has an offset of 0x28 for every possible instance. This is the function I'm using to get the name from the instance:

```
std::string* GetName(int Instance) {
    return (std::string*)(*(int*)(Instance + 0x28));
}
```

I've used a debugger/disassembler to verify that the instance is valid and that the resulting pointer has the value that I need. However, as soon as I try to do something with it, the game crashes. For example, this:

```
std::string objName = *GetName(obj);
```

Or this:

```
std::cout << *GetName(obj);
```

Or even this (when I got desperate enough):

```
std::string* objName = (std::string*) obj + 0x28;
std::cout << *objName;
```

I tried attaching my IDE's debugger to the game, and the most useful information I got was "segmentation fault" when the crash happened. Even my much more knowledgeable friends who helped me out with this are stumped as to what could be wrong.

If there isn't enough information here to find out what the problem is, could I at least get a nudge in the right direction? What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: It's probably a C-string (0 terminated), aka `char*`. Rather than coercing the memory to a `std::string*`, coerce it to a `char*` and then construct a new `std::string` instance from it. If you want to also read and write to it, you'll need to work with it as a `char*` (C-string) at any rate. Given your current understanding of memory and C++ types, it might be a bit too challenging a project to play around with memory in such a way.

Comment: @MicroVirus Thanks for the help. When you say "construct a new std::string instance from it," what exactly do you mean? Are you referring to something specific?

Comment: @MicroVirus I figured it out and it's sort of working now! I'm able to output stuff, but it's just gibberish. That's still better than nothing and I think it must just mean that I need to look elsewhere for the name. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by MacroVirus in a comment, the solution was to store the value in a char* then convert that to a new std::string instance. It now works flawlessly. Here is the revised function:

```
char* GetName(int Instance) {
    return (char*)(*(int*)(Instance + 0x28));
}
```

Thank you for the help! This was driving me crazy.